# How To Add Textbox With DDL Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Straight to the point, I use ASP.NET 3.5 (C#), I have 3 items in my dropdown list.
So, I want to make events within the ddl validation.
For instance,

```
if (ddl.selectedvalue ==1) { One textbox added to my form }
else if (ddl.selectedvalue==2) { Two textbox added to my form}
```

Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form open place holder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeHolderID" runat="server" />
```

And now your code  in .cs file

```
if (ddl.selectedvalue ==1) 
{
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
txt1.ID = "newTxt1";
placeHolderID.Controls.Add(txt1);

}
```

Similar for next Condition.

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' while validating the ddl.. Is there smth wrong with this?

Comment: if (ddl.selectedvalue == "1") may be help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your form open place holder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeHolderID" runat="server" />
```

And now your code in .cs file

You can write code like below ,

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.selectedvalue.ToString());

for(int i = 1; i < value + 1 ; i ++)
{
  TextBox txt = new TextBox();
  txt.ID = "newTxt" + i;
  placeHolderID.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

Comment: What is the function of place holder here, @Lajja Thaker?

Comment: Really your code help me so much..
Really thank you, if I can select both of you all answers, I might be done it.. :)